# What does the expression 'stands packed' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

The expression:

> 1) It's Regionals and we want those **stands packed**!
>
> 2) I want the **stands packed** with every man that remotely resembles my father

links to the expressions: [#1](https://twitter.com/MWPrincipal/status/831267205220298753) | [#2](https://youtu.be/HytBpPSCELs?t=54)

---

Question:

> What does the expression **'stands packed'** mean?

---

There [is](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stand) no word about it

Comment: Canned sardines are **packed** into their cans, that is, all available space is taken up by the sardines.  A room can be (figuratively)  **packed with people**, that is, very crowded. A politician might tell his operatives, "When I give this speech, I want that room packed".  He wants the operatives to make sure the room is filled with people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are stands, specifically stadium stands:

[image: Stadium stands]

From Google images.

It just means that whoever is talking wants a lot of people in the stands of the sports stadium watching whatever event is happening.

[This is the definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stands) you want:

> noun, 9. Rows of wooden or metal benches placed one above another for people watching a sports event or a performance.

This definition is also hidden in the link you provided:

> noun 4. A large raised tiered structure for spectators, typically at a sporting venue.